# How to update ruby from 1.9.3 to 2.3.1 in ubuntu 14.04 32 bit?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rbenv

Now, I am using ubuntu 14.04 32 bit OS. I have previously  installed ruby 1.9.3 and now I am trying to install ruby 2.3.1 using "rbenv install -v 2.3.1". When I ran this it is say successfully installed. But when I am running "ruby -v" it showing ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [i686-linux]. What should I do to update my ruby now???

Comment: Don't know..but just maybe try typing `bash --login` and then `ruby -v`. What does it say? It has worked for me earlier..

Comment: It worked. But when I restart terminal the result is same.

Comment: You should really go consult a rbenv tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

I too had that problem before, but now I solved it. Try the following steps:

1. Add the `ppa:brightbox/ruby-ng` repository:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:brightbox/ruby-ng
   $ sudo apt-get update
   ```
2. Install the package:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install ruby2.3 ruby2.3-dev
   ```
3. And you’re up and running:

   ```
   $ ruby2.3 -v

   ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
   ```

Answer (score 0):

[Reference](https://askubuntu.com/a/413905)

- Open the terminal
- From menu-bar, select Edit > Profiles
- In opened prompt Edit > Default
- In Tab "Title & Commands" -> check "Run Command as Login Shell"
- Restart Terminal

Now this makes it your default setup and need not login after restart.

Hope it helps.